# object Object returning on one set of values but not the other

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm having an [object Object] return where I'm expecting a value.  None of the other posts have been able to help me out.

I'm working on an application that is supposed to take form input and build html for them to copy and paste into a form that takes limited html input.  Its purpose is to allow someone without HTML knowledge to be able to upload the correct HTML.

I've gotten most of the form to work as expected.  However I can't get the add amenities button to populate in the output section.  The form itself works great.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: amenities"  id="#amenities">
    <li>
        <input data-bind='value: title' /><a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeAmenity'>Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul style='font-weight:600;padding:10px;box-shadow:5px 5px grey;border:solid 1px;' data-bind='foreach: amenities'>
    <li style='margin-left:10px;' data-bind='text: title' />
</ul>
```

It iterates through and displays correctly.  But when I iterate through the output:

```
something += "</p><hr/><ul style='font-weight:600;padding:10px;box-shadow:5px 5px grey;border:solid 1px;'>";
    something += $.each(self.amenities(), function(){
        return ("<li>" + self.amenities() + "</li>"); 
    });
```

All I get is the object Object as a return.  It won't give me the value. Again, I've looked at all the other object Object posts on SO and none of the solutions worked for me.  Here is the jsfiddle for reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/8hydr/3/

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are concatenating an object with a string. I don't really understand the usage of the `$.each` in your code. Actually it doesn't make sense.

If you want to return a string representation of a `li` element for each object of the retuned array (*by calling the function*) you should use `$.map` which returns an array, then you can `join` the array's elements and convert them to a string:

```
//                      [Object, Object, ...]
//                      ^   ^-------^-----^----
//                      |                      |
something += $.map(self.amenities(), function(value) {
    return "<li>" + value.title + "</li>"; 
}).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `$.each`

```
    $.each(self.amenities(), function(x){
        something +=  "<li>" + self.amenities()[x].title + "</li>"; 
    });
```

Reason you're getting [Object] is because you're not telling it which property out of the object in the array you want to pull out. You've named it title, so you need to tell it. Also you weren't iterating through the array properly.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8hydr/5/